# rectangular groups are completely simple and orthodox

Tags: group-theory, semigroups

Let $S$ be a rectangular group. i.e $S$ is isomorphic to the direct product of a group and a rectangular band.

1. Show that a semigroup is completely simple and orthodox if and only if it is a rectangular group.
2. Show that $S$ is a rectangular group if and only if it is completely regular and satisfies the law

$$x^{-1}yy^{-1}x=x^{-1}x$$

I have now shown all of this besides the first implication in 1., that a completely simple and orthodox semigroup is a rectangular group. I believe I have to use the Rees Theorem, but I am not quite sure where I am supposed to use orthodox in my argument?

Comment: Can you tell us why you're interested in this problem or its solution?

Comment: I have been studying semigroups at university, and I am currently revising for my exams. I came across this question which seems to incorporate quite a lot of my knowledge, but I can't understand where to begin. I think I may have shown that S being a rectangular group implies that its orthodox, and possibly also that it has primitive idempotents, but the rest I am currently confused by, so i wanted to see how different people might go about the problem so I could try and look at similar problems in the same way.

Comment: Thank you, and welcome to MSE! fyi: Unfortunately, because you did not include any context in your question, four people have already voted to close it, so it only takes a single person to snipe it at this point. Hopefully that doesn't happen (HEY, CLOSE-QUEUE: DON'T LET IT HAPPEN) but it would be even less likely if you edited your question to include that information. [Myself, I do not know a semigroup from a hole in the ground so I can't actually answer the question.]

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Sorry I didnt think to include context! I always find a helpful way of learning maths is to watch other peoples approaches to problems, and see if you can somehow adopt a similar style, so that is what I am looking for here!

Comment: Welcome! It's usually better to start your post with the actual question, as in the list of questions all we can see is the title (which doesn't say much) and the generic prologue ("I have been studying..." etc.) So, first the question and in the end of the post you can explain the context and the situation.

Comment: I think you still need to improve your question before it can be answered. Isn't a rectangular group the direct product of a group and a rectangular band? With the definition you've given every semigroup is rectangular group (it's the direct product of itself with a one element rectangular band). Also in part 2 of your question, what is x to the power -1? In an arbitrary semigroup x^-1 isn't usually defined.

Comment: That is word for word how the question is structured, taken from 'fundamentals of semigroup theory' by John Howie.

Comment: You are right about part 2 but not about the definition of a right group. A semigroup $S$ is called a rectangular group if it is isomorphic to the direct product of a GROUP and a rectangular band.

Comment: My complete mistake, I've honestly been staring at this so long I couldn't see the error! Yes you are 100%, correct, that is meant to say group.

Comment: A proof for this is apparently in Introduction to semigroups by Mario Petrich, but unfortunately my university doesn't have the book!

Comment: I'm just typing a solution to part 1. Didn't think about part 2 yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for part 2.

Suppose $S$ is a rectangular group so is isomorphic to $G$ x $B$ for a group $G$ and a rectangular band $B$. To show a semigroup is completely regular we have to show there is a unary operation from $a$ to $a^{-1}$ s.t;

i.) $(a^{-1})^{-1}=a$

ii.) $aa^{-1}a=a$

iii.) $aa^{-1}=a^{-1}a$

In $S$ define this inverse as $(g^{-1},a)$ for the element $(g,a)$. By simple calculation using multiplication in  a direct product we can see all three conditions stated above are satisfied by this operation. So we can conclude that $S$ is completely regular.

It is also a very simple matter to show the equation $x^{-1}yy^{-1}x=x^{-1}x$ is satisfied by letting $x=(g,a), x^{-1}=(g^{-1},a), y=(h,b), y^{-1}=(h^{-1},b)$, remembering that $B$ is a rectangular band.

Conversely, suppose $S$ is completely regular and satisfies $x^{-1}yy^{-1}x=x^{-1}x$. We will show $S$ is completely simple and orthodox and hence $S$ is a rectangular group by part 1.

To show $S$ is completely simple we first show it is simple, so we show $\mathcal{J}=S$ x $S$. Let $a,b \in{S}$. Need to find $x,y,u,v \in{S^1}$ such that $xay=b, ubv=a$. Let $x=bb^{-1}, y=a^{-1}b, u=aa^{-1}, v=b^{-1}a$. Subsitituing this into the above and using $x^{-1}yy^{-1}x=x^{-1}x$ to simplify we see $a$ $\mathcal{J}$ $b$ for all $a,b \in{S}$, so $\mathcal{J}=S$ x $S$ and hence $S$ is simple. Using Proposition 4.1.2 from Howie we can conclude $S$ is completely simple.

Now to show $S$ is orthodox we must show it is regular and the idempotents form a subsemigroup. Clearly $S$ is regular as its completely regular. Suppose $e,f$ are idempotents of $S$. As $S$ is completely regular we know i) ii) and iii) are all satisfied. so consider;
\begin{equation*}
e=ee^{-1}e=e^{-1}ee=e^{-1}e=(e^{-1}e)(e^{-1}e)=(e^{-1}e)(ee^{-1})=e^{-1}ee^{-1}=e^{-1}
\end{equation*}

Similarly $f=f^{-1}$. Consider $x^{-1}yy^{-1}x=x^{-1}x$. This holds for all $x,y \in{S}$, so in particular it holds for $e,f$, so;

\begin{equation*}
e^{-1}ff^{-1}e=e^{-1}e \: \Rightarrow \: effe=ee \: \Rightarrow \: efe=e
\end{equation*}

Hence $efef=ef$ so $ef$ is an idempotent so the idempotents form a subsemigroups, so $S$ is orthodox. Hence by applying 1. we get the deisred result.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an answer for part 1:

Suppose $S$ is a rectangular group. Then $S=G\times R$ where $G$ is a group and $R=I\times \Lambda$ is a rectangular band. If $(g,r)\in S$ is an idempotent, then $(g,r)^2=(g,r)$ and so $g^2=g$ and $g$ is the identity of $G$. Hence the idempotents of $S$ are of the form $\{e\}\times R$, and this is clearly a subsemigroup. Hence $S$ is orthodox.

The semigroup $S$ is also simple. If $(e,r), (e,s)\in S$ are idempotents and $(e, r)(e,s)=(e,s)(e,r)=(e,s)$, then $rs=sr=s$. If $r=(i,\lambda)$ and $s=(j,\mu)$, then $rs= (i,\mu)$ and $sr=(j,\lambda)$ and so $r=s$.  It follows that $(e,s)$ is primitive, and so $S$ is completely simple.

For the converse, suppose that $S$ is completely simple and orthodox. By the Rees Theorem (Theorem 3.3.1 in Howie), every completely simple semigroup is isomorphic to a Rees matrix semigroup $\mathcal{M}[G; I, \Lambda; P]$ where $G$ is a group, $I$ and $\Lambda$ are some sets, and $P$ is a $|\Lambda|\times |I|$ matrix with entries in $G$. Since the set of elements of $S=\mathcal{M}[G; I, \Lambda; P]$ is $I\times G\times \Lambda$ it suffices to prove that the multiplication in $S$ is the same as the multiplication in direct product of the group $G$ with the rectangular band $I\times \Lambda$. For this it suffices to show that every entry of the matrix $P$ is the identity of $G$. By Theorem 3.4.2 in Howie, we can assume without loss of generality that the first row and first column of $P$ can be chosen to consist solely of the identity $1_G$ of the group $G$. 
In other words, we can assume that $1\in I\cap \Lambda$, and $p_{i, 1}=p_{1, \lambda}=1_G$ for all $i\in I$ and $\lambda\in\Lambda$.

Let $i\in I$ and $\lambda\in \Lambda$ be arbitrary. The element $(i,p_{\lambda, i}^{-1}, \lambda)$ is the only idempotent with first position $i$ and last position $\lambda$. Since $S$ is orthodox and $(i, p_{1,i}^{-1}, 1), (1, p_{1, \lambda}^{-1}, \lambda)$ are idempotents, it follows that 
$$(i, p_{1,i}^{-1}, 1), (1, p_{1, \lambda}^{-1}, \lambda)=(i, p_{1,i}^{-1}p_{1,1}p_{1,\lambda}^{-1}, \lambda)$$
is an idempotent too. But the only idempotent starting with $i$ and ending with $\lambda$ is 
$(i,p_{\lambda, i}^{-1}, \lambda)$ and so $p_{\lambda, i}^{-1}=1_G$, as required.

Comment: I was wondering, Can I write the elements of $S$ in the form $I$ x $G$ x $\Lambda$, but can i swap this order round to give $G$ x $I$ x $\Lambda$? Then keeping the same rules for multiplication, $(a,(i,\lambda))(b,(j,\mu))=(ap_{\lambda j}b, (i, \mu))$ and then the multiplication defined on $I$ x $\Lambda$ gives by Theorem 1.1.3 in Howie, a rectangular band? Only issue is that doesnt use orthodox so I was lost.

Comment: Also in your solution, why is it enought to show every element of $P$ is the identity? Thank you so so much for your help by the way, hugely appreciated!

Comment: You can swap the order, keeping the same rules for multiplication. If every entry of the matrix is the identity of G then the multiplication in the Rees matrix semigroup and in the direct product of G with IxLambda is the same. If some entry of the matrix is not the identity, then the multiplication is not the same. Try writing out an example of a Rees matrix semigroup over a matrix with every entry equal the identity of the group you choose. Then write out the direct product of the group and I x Lambda, you'll see right away that they are the same.

Comment: And if you solved part 2, then please post the answer too!

Comment: Will do when i get a minute. It essentially converts part 2. into part 1. Also I am still lost with why showing all entrieds must be the identity? That doesn't necessarily mean $G=\{e\}$ does it? just to be sure. So if every element of $P$ is 1, then all elements of the Rees Matrix semigroup are of the form $(i, gh, \mu)$ yes? then if i take the product of elements in $G$ x $I$ x $\Lambda$ by considering $(g,i,\lambda)(h,j,\mu)=(gh, ij, \lambda \mu)$ which isnt the same?

Comment: Just got it, love it when maths just clicks! thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: sorry this answer took longer than it should have for me to actually get down on the computer!